# Alphabetically Sorting a Linked List

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Is there a general template for sorting a singly linked list alphabetically? The other posts on here have post-specific code and what I am looking for is more of a broad solution that I can tweak and use repeatedly in the future. I'd even appreciate just a link to somewhere that has an explanation of how to build my own template.

Comment: Grab a linked list implementation, include a char array/string in structure, make compare function, start swapping entries as needed for sorting.  C doesn't do templates unfortunately - this is where containers in C++ really shine.

Comment: If you want your sorting to be somewhat performant, consider using an array instead of a linked list. If your members can vary in size, an array of pointers will do. For arrays, there's already the generic `qsort()` in the standard lib.

Comment: Check out the below link. Might be useful in your case.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175782/sorting-linked-list-alphabetically-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mergesort algorithm for linked list could be useful for you. It's use is generic where you could alter it to your use case. There is also some C code for you to follow along with.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html